# How to write a custom formula so that Drag option does not take the cell formula in series?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with revenues generated daily. For Saturdays, sundays and other public holidays, the cell will be empty.

In another sheet I need to generate a weekly report where I need to show only the last generated revenue of that week. For example, a week starts from Monday and ends with Sunday. Satruday and sunday cells will be empty. So in Sheet2 A1 I should display Friday's revenue. Or if the current day is tuesday, it should show tuesday's revenue. I used the below formula to populate the value.

```
=IF('Sheet1'!A1<>"",IF('Sheet1'!B1<>"",IF('Sheet1'!C1<>"",IF('Sheet1'!D1<>"",IF('Sheet1'!E1<>"",IF('Sheet1'!F1<>"",IF('Sheet1'!G1<>"",'Sheet1'!G1,'Sheet1'!F1),'Sheet1'!E1),'Sheet1'!D1),'Sheet1'!C1),'Sheet1'!B1),'Sheet1'!A1),"")
```

However if I drag from cell A1 to B1 in sheet 2, it should consider week2 days, ie., column 8 to 14 and so on,  but not 2 to 8.

So what would be the excel formula that I should be using?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help [Using Absolute and Relative Formula References](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/relative-and-absolute-formulas.php)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft give [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152407) formula to determine which is the last cell filled with data:

```
=OFFSET(<StartCell>,0,MATCH(MAX(Range)+1,<Range>,1)-1)
```

Using OFFSET to get the range to check, and ROW() to determine which area, we can make the start cell `OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0)` (assuming you have this in the 1st row, otherwise alter the **-1** in the formula).  The range becomes almost the same, but we tell `OFFSET` to return 7 cells: `OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0,7)`. We use **$** to fix the cell, as we don't want to have to calculate offset from a variable position. This gives the full formula as:

```
=OFFSET(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0),MATCH(MAX(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0,7))+1,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0,7),1)-1,0)
```

and this can be copied down as far as needed - you will start to get **#N/A** when the formula runs out of data to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Any easier way of doing this might be to have a hidden row that looks to see if cell A1, B1 etc has a value in it, and to see if the next one is blank.  And return a 1 when that statement is true, because that'll be the last one.

Then you just lookup the column that has a 1 in it using V or HLOOKUP.

It's easier to read, and you can use it across many more columns without having to make your formula bigger.